# Slick2D ingoring aplha channel?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, slick, alpha

When I use the draw method inside a image, it completely ingores the alpha channel and fills it in with white. Is there a way I can draw it where the alpha is see through like it's suppost to be? I would look at their website but

Comment: you would look at their website but what?

Comment: Show the code you use to load the image

Comment: Make sure you are loading an image type that supports transparency, provide the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

If you are using OpenGL to draw the image then this enables alpha channel blending.

Sources:
LWJGL Wiki and
Trial and Error